# force one element get between tow sibling elements

Tags: html, css

I need that my responsive page will force full screen element get between sibling elements when display on mobile?[on desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRBRU.jpg) [on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCYLy.jpg).

I have 3 (div) elements, tow in a row div and one on other div. what do I need to do to force the blue element to get between the orange and the yellow divs when display on mobile?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
     <div class="row orange"></div>
    <div class="row yellow"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
    <div class="row blue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Add your code in the question to understand what you want.

Comment: Hello, please take a time to go through the welcome tour to know your way around here , read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
       <div class="orange"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
       <div class="yellow"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
       <div class="blue"></div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>

css:
.container{
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.orange {
  float:left;
  background: orange;
  padding: 20px 30px;
}
@media (min-width: 992px){
  .yellow {
     float:left;
     padding: 20px 30px;
     background: yellow;
     height: 400px;
   }
}/*not always necessary*/
@media (max-width: 992px){
  .yellow {
     float:left;
     padding: 20px 30px;
     background: yellow;
   }
}
 @media (min-width: 992px){
  .blue {
    float:left;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0px;
   }
  }
```